# Is it better to track bugs in lists (e.g. github issues, redmine) or in kanban boards (e.g. jira, trello)?

Tags: project-management, issue-tracking, bug-report

I need to decide on a bug tracking solution for our small dev team of 4 developers working on a web-based SaaS tool. There is plenty of products out there to use but one major difference seems to be if you either keep your bugs in a list (for example like GitHub issues or Redmine) or in a kanban board (for example like Jira or Trello).

Which method do you prefer and why?

Comment: see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: It is best to track them how your team works.  GitHub lists work just fine, but if you use Kanban or Scrum boards, a tool that supports that is a little better.  However, there is **no reason** you can't use a GitHub list and make cards for a physical Kanban board.  Use something, then figure out if it needs to be customized for your workflow.

Comment: We don't use a kanban board (yet). Only occasionally for larger milestones, we will use one on a whiteboard for 2-4 weeks until that milestone is finished.
Since we're a small team sitting next to each other we do most planning by talking to each other. We do get however 10-20 bug reports a week so we need something for that.

Comment: @gnat thanks for the tip. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: unfortunately, edit didn't help much: "avoid asking subjective questions where …  every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”" ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: @tcam: As with many things in software development, it depends.  How small is your team?  I find a kanban board useful for a team of two or larger.

Comment: @RobertHarvey We are 4 developers. But why particular do you find it more useful than lists?

Comment: I've never used Redmine, At my last job, they used Trello extensively; there was one Trello board per department.  Maybe Trello does a bit more than a Kanban board, but I'd never go back to a Todo list again unless it was especially robust software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be important to distinguish between bug tracking and work tracking.

If I put a 'bug' in jira, or a kanban board it generally represents 'a task to fix this bug'

However if I report a bug in a product, that doesn't necessarily mean that there will be a task raised to fix that bug. I will want to put it on a defects board or bug tracking system.

Internal bugs with a small team the distinction is probably unimportant. But its something to bear in mind when deciding your solution.

edit:

here is an example bug tracker

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/buglist.cgi?chfield=%5BBug%20creation%5D&chfieldfrom=24h

Comment: Just to clarify: You are using a list for bug tracking and you'll only forward some of those into a Kanban board? What happens to the other bugs?

Comment: the usual triage, is it really incorrect behaviour, how serious is it, is there a work around, is the product still supported etc.

Comment: Ah, I see you use the list as a filter/backlog but the "real bugs" go into a board.
We don't get that many bugs reported, so using both systems seems like overkill in our use case.

Comment: no. the bug tracking system has real bugs with states. a 'task to fix a bug' isnt the same as a bug

Comment: So most bugs in your list will eventually end up having a "task to fix a bug" in your kanban?

Comment: It really doesn't matter. The point is that you need to track both things. bugs and work